# scrape Reference number from a web site

Tags: python

I create a python script that gets data after entering the Reference number. that part is done.

Now I'm trying to get the Reference number for each capital from https://register.fca.org.uk/s/search?q=capital&type=Companies webpage using python.

this is the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time


url = 'https://register.fca.org.uk/s/search?q=capital&type=Companies'
service = Service('link to chromedriver')

service.start()
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url)

driver.get(url);
html = driver.page_source 
time.sleep(1)
print(html)
driver.quit()
```

I could find the Reference number in html varable.

could anyone point me to the right direction, how can I get this? there are almost 7000 Reference numbers so write it to the list manually is not a solution.

Thanks.

EDIT:
After fixing the previous issue, I tried to do this kind of thing. navigate to new web page and comes back to the previous web page.

```
for d in divs:

  RN = ''
  companyName = ''
  companyName =   d.find_element_by_tag_name('h2').text
  RNData = d.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="result-card_figure-offset"]').text
  RN = RNData.split(':')[1].strip()

  d.click()
  time.sleep(12)

  phoneNumber = ''
  phoneNumberData =  driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="who-is-this-details-content"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]')
  phoneNumber = phoneNumberData[0].text.split('\n')[1]

  print(RN)
  print(companyName)
  print(phoneNumber)

  driver.execute_script("history.back();")
```

it gives me this Error.

```
  selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? Do you get error message? Always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: this page uses JavaScript and `requests`,`BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: i used selenium.

Comment: you should say it at start.

Comment: did you try to use `find_elements_by_xpath` or other method to get anythink? Did you try to `sleep` longer? I have to `sleep` 12 seconds to see data in Firefox window.

Comment: I'm sorry,I forgot to add code :)

Comment: i sleep 50 seconds but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You didn't describe details of problem - so I don't know what is your problem

I tested this code with different drivers and it always works for me without any problems.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

url = 'https://register.fca.org.uk/s/search?q=capital&type=Companies'

#service = Service('/home/furas/bin/chromedriver')
service = Service('/home/furas/bin/geckodriver')
service.start()
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url)

#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(12)

divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="result-card_main"]')

for d in divs:
    # name
    print('Name:', d.find_element_by_tag_name('h2').text)
    
    # reference
    print(d.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[contains(text(), "Ref")]').text)
    # or
    print(d.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="result-card_figure-offset"]').text)
    
    print('---')
    
#driver.quit()
```

Result:

```
Name: Capital Com (UK) Limited
Reference number: 793714
Reference number: 793714
---
Name: Capital Partners Group Ltd
Reference number: 435916
Reference number: 435916
---
Name: Capital Professional Limited
Reference number: 578614
Reference number: 578614
---
Name: Capital Advisory Partners Ltd
Reference number: 450657
Reference number: 450657
---
Name: Capital Asset Management (Financial Planning) Ltd
Reference number: 225112
Reference number: 225112
---
Name: Capital One (Europe) plc
Reference number: 204440
Reference number: 204440
---
Name: Capital Com SV Investments Ltd
Reference number: 778391
Reference number: 778391
---
Name: Capital Claims Ltd
Reference number: 838982
Reference number: 838982
---
Name: Capital & Income Solutions Ltd
Reference number: 462885
Reference number: 462885
---
Name: Capital Financial Management Limited
Reference number: 300991
Reference number: 300991
---
Name: Capital Generation Partners LLP
Reference number: 474602
Reference number: 474602
---
Name: Capital Home Loans Limited
Reference number: 307798
Reference number: 307798
---
Name: Capital Document Solutions Limited
Reference number: 672340
Reference number: 672340
---
Name: Capital Investements Ltd
Reference number: 925227
Reference number: 925227
---
Name: Capital D Management LLP
Reference number: 808170
Reference number: 808170
---
Name: Capital Asset Management Ltd
Reference number: 503091
Reference number: 503091
---
Name: CAPITAL PLUS PARTNERS LIMITED
Reference number: 189495
Reference number: 189495
---
Name: Capital Trust Limited
Reference number: 124573
Reference number: 124573
---
Name: Capital International Limited
Reference number: 119193
Reference number: 119193
---
Name: Capital Index (UK) Limited
Reference number: 709693
Reference number: 709693
---
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but why all the loops have the same Reference number? How can I change this?

Comment: I forgot to add dot to make relative xpath. Now it is corrected. `'.//div[contains(text(), "Ref")]` and `'.//div[@class="result-card_figure-offset"]'`